# python code to print number of digits present in a string

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that generates 100 random integers for a list between 0 and 9 and displays the count for each time a number is present in the list.  Been fumbling around with this for two days.  Below is the closest of all the ugly hacks I've tried.
My output is always zero for some reason using several attempts.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
#Count single digits
import random

rand = []

num = 0
while num < 10:
    num = num + 1
    int = [random.randint(0, 9)]
    #print(rand, end="")
    rand.append(int)

print(rand)
print("")


print("Number of zeros is ", rand.count(0))
print("Number of ones is ", rand.count(1))
print("Number of twos is ", rand.count(2))
print("Number of threes is ", rand.count(3))
print("Number of fours is ", rand.count(4))
print("Number of fives is ", rand.count(5))
print("Number of sixes is ", rand.count(6))
print("Number of sevens is ", rand.count(7))
print("Number of eights is ", rand.count(8))
print("Number of nines is ", rand.count(9))
```

Output:

```
[[8], [6], [1], [8], [7], [0], [4], [7], [8], [7]]

Number of zeros is  0
Number of ones is  0
Number of twos is  0
Number of threes is  0
Number of fours is  0
Number of fives is  0
Number of sixes is  0
Number of sevens is  0
Number of eights is  0
Number of nines is  0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your `rand` list ends up containing a bunch of single element lists:

```
[[8], [6], [1], [8], [7], [0], [4], [7], [8], [7]]
```

That's because you wrap each entry in a list here:

```
int = [random.randint(0, 9)]
```

When you count the number of `0`s (for example) in the list, the answer is `0` because the list only contains instances of `[0]`, not `0`.

Try this instead:

```
int = random.randint(0, 9)
```

Then your `rand` list will look more like this:

```
[8, 6, 1, 8, 7, 0, 4, 7, 8, 7]
```

And your counting will work properly.

Comment: yup, as soon as I posted this and went back into my code I tried that on my own.  Love how posting to this site makes you focus on what you are doing a lot better than if you didn't.  I screwed with this for two days!  Thanks for you crazy fast responses though!

Comment: @user2363753 -- that even has a name.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: love the wiki link.  that makes a lot of sense to me, as I do not have a team to talk to while I do this work...  SO much more difficult to learn on your own.

Comment: @user2363753 -- I understand. Most of my programming life has been on my own.  Even now I work with a team, but remotely -- so its much harder for me to grab someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import collections, random
>>> nums = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(10)]
>>> nums
[5, 9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 8, 1, 2, 1]
>>> counts = collections.Counter(nums)
>>> counts
Counter({1: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})
>>> counts[1]
2
>>> counts[6]
0
```